# iOS - accessing array returned by API gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1)

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, exc-bad-access

I am trying to make a Facebook/9gag like comment page in an iOS app. Briefly speaking, there will be a list of images in a list view, and there is a comment button, wheneven users press it, a comment list view will be shown just like those in Facebook and 9gag.

In my project, I created several classes to achieve this, which are:

1. APIOperator, which defines the path of the api to call, and called whenever a request is made to the server
2. MyPhotoCell, which is a custom UITableViewCell class forming the photo list view, consisting an image and a comment button
3. CommentViewController, which is the controller for the comment list displayed
4. CommentCell, which is a custom UITableViewCell forming the comment list displayed

And below are the code segments regarding the issue:

Firstly, when the user presses the comment button in one of the MyPhotoCell, it will invoke the creation of CommentListViewController:

```
//MyPhotoCell.m
- (void)click_btn_comment:(id)sender 
{
    CommentViewController *comment_view = [[CommentViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CommentViewController" bundle:nil];
    comment_view.targetPhotoid = self.photoItem.photoid;
    [[MyAppCoreData coreData].navController pushViewController:comment_view animated:YES];
}
```

Following with:

```
//CommentViewController.h
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger targetPhotoid;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *arr_commentList;

//CommentViewController.m
@interface SecondCreation_CommentViewController ()<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
   ASIHTTPRequest *request_comment;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UITableView *tbl_comment;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *page;

@end

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if(!self.tbl_comment){
        self.tbl_comment = [[UITableView alloc] init];
        self.tbl_comment.delegate = self;
        self.tbl_comment.dataSource = self;

        self.tbl_comment.frame = CGRectMake(0, 55, PHOTOWIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT - 100);
        [self.view addSubview:self.tbl_comment];
    }

    if([NSArray checkEmptyArray:self.arr_commentList]){
        self.page = 0;
        [self sendRequest:1];
    }

}

 - (void)addDisplayData:(NSArray *)arr_addData withReset:(BOOL)reset
{
    //NSLog here shows arr_addData has a count of 6 (6 comments inside, which is normal)
    //NSLog here shows arr_commentList has a count of 0 (which is also expected)
    if (reset) {
        [self.arr_commentList removeAllObjects];
    }else {
        if (!self.arr_commentList) {
            self.arr_commentList = [NSMutableArray array];
        }
    }
    [self.arr_commentList addObjectsFromArray:arr_addData];
    //NSLog here shows arr_addData still has a count of 6
    //NSLog here shows arr_commentList has a count of 6
}

- (void)sendRequest:(NSInteger)page
{
    __block typeof(self)blockSelf = self;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        blockSelf -> request_comment = [APIOperator getCommentListForPhoto:@(self.targetPhotoid) andPage:page WithCompletionHandler:^(APISTATUS apiStatus, CommentListItem *commentListItem, ASIHTTPRequest *request) {
            if (request != blockSelf -> request_comment) {
                return;
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
                if (apiStatus == APISTATUS_SUCCESS) {
                    //I tried to access and print out the content of the returned commentList here, and it gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 1 ......)
                    //e.g. NSLog(((CommentItem *)[commentListItem.commentList objectAtIndex:0]).message);

                    //I tried to assign the returned commentList to my controller through various ways like:
                    //[blockSelf.arr_commentList addObjectsFromArray:commentListItem.commentList];
                    //[blockSelf.arrcommentList = commentListItem.commentList;
                    //[blockSelf addDisplayData:commentListItem.commentList withReset:YES];
                    //I tried to access the content of controller's arr_commentList, it will give EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 1, .....) too
                } else {

                }
            });
        }];
    });
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"commentcell";
    CommentCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if(!cell)
        cell = [[CommentCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];

    //acessing the local arr_commentList here will also gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 1.....)

    return cell;
}
```

And finally, the APIOperator class where the api request is made(ASIHTTPREQUEST is a wrapper class that used to send HTTP request to server and interacts with RESTFUL api, link: [link here](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)):

```
//APIOperator.m
+ (ASIHTTPRequest *)getCommentListForPhoto:(NSNumber *)photoid andPage:(NSInteger)page WithCompletionHandler:(void(^)(APISTATUS apiStatus, CommentListItem *apiItem, ASIHTTPRequest *request))completionBlock
{
    NSString *str_page = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @(page)];
    //API_URL here is the url to call the api in the server
    NSString *str_API = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",API_URL];
    ASIHTTPRequest *_request = [ASIHTTPRequest createAPIRequest:str_API];

    __block ASIHTTPRequest *request = _request;
    __block void(^tempBlock)(APISTATUS apiStatus, CommentListItem *apiItem, ASIHTTPRequest *request) = completionBlock;
    [_request setCompletionBlock:^{

        if ([request responseStatusCode] == 200 || [request responseStatusCode] == 302 || [request responseStatusCode] == 304) {

            DEBUGMSG(@"%d %@",[request responseStatusCode], request.url)
            JSONParse *jsonParse = [[JSONParse alloc] initWithData:[request responseData]];
            CommentListItem *obj = (CommentListItem *)[jsonParse parser2OneObject:@"CommentListItem" withPath:nil];

            //I tried to print out the contents of the comments here, and everything are as expected
            NSLog(((CommentItem *)[obj.commentList objectAtIndex:0]).message);

            jsonParse = nil;
            if (tempBlock) {
                tempBlock(APISTATUS_SUCCESS,obj,request);
            }

            tempBlock = nil;
            request = nil;

        } else {

            DEBUGMSG(@"%d %@",[request responseStatusCode], request.url)
            if (tempBlock) {
                tempBlock(apiStatus,nil,request);
            }
            tempBlock = nil;
            request = nil;
        }

    }];
    [_request setFailedBlock:^{

        DEBUGMSG(@"%d %@",[request responseStatusCode], request.url)
        if (tempBlock) {
            tempBlock(apiStatus,nil,request);
        }
        tempBlock = nil;
        request = nil;

    }];
    [_request performSelector:@selector(startAsynchronous)];

    return _request;
}
```

I searched on the internet and found out that EXC_BAD_ACCESS code = 1 is about accessing/releasing a variable that is already released/deallocated before, but I still can't figure out the problem here. I can't find where it is released/deallocated, and why it still give me a count of 6 if it is released/deallocated. Hope I can get some help here about what is causing this problem and how to deal with it, as I've already dealing with this problem for a long time, but still have no idea about what the problem is and what to do. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should enable zombie objects for your current development scheme which will then tell you exactly what released object is being accessed. It may not be what you think it is.

Comment: I enabled zombie object, and it gives *** -[CFString retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xda4ba00, so I guess the reutrned commentListItem.commentList is released when I access it in the controller?

Comment: is ```commentList``` a string?  if not, then that is not likely what is released.  what line is it breaking on with zombies enabled?

Comment: It is breaking on NSLog(((CommentItem *)[commentListItem.commentList objectAtIndex:0]).message);, in CommentViewController, where I tried to access the message string of the first CommentItem in the commentList array of commentListItem. commentList is an array consist of 6 CommentItem.

Comment: this may seem silly, but does your ```CommentItem``` object only have a weak reference to ```message```?

Comment: Oh my god! I just checked my class and I found that I set message to `assign`, which I thought I set it to `strong`. Changed it to `strong` then everything is fine. Really thanks a lot!

Comment: i'm glad you got it figured out! i have definitely made that simple mistake a time or two. :)